# Cypher Program on C# with a function

Tags: c#

Why doesn't my code work?? I am writing a cypher program in C# and would like to know why this isn't working. The error that I keep on getting is 'not all code paths return a value'
this is my code:

[image: code]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: So shell we randomly guess what your code is? Show it to us, otherwise our hands are tied.

Comment: Going by that notification. I'd say that you have a method with a return value. And one of the paths in the method does not contain a return statement. Ah yes. If your `word` is empty your foreach loop will not engage. There should be a return statement bellow the foreach loop

Comment: Added it now!!!

Comment: if `foreach` never executes `cypher` does not return value

Comment: And moreover, it cypher only the first character from string.

Comment: There should be button that gives electrics shocks to people who paste images instead of code.

Comment: [why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If passed string will be empty then the `return` will never be hit, so the method will not return anything.

```
public static string cypher(string word)
{
    // If word is null, we just return null.
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
      return null;

    // Process string. This will return after first char...
    foreach (char d in word)
    {
        char charCypher = System.Convert.ToChar((int)d+2);
        return Convert.ToString(charCypher);
    }
}
```

---

Not exactly what the question is about, but you iterate through each char of a word, but you return after first char. You probably want to cypher every char and return cyphered word. In this case you need to modify your code:

```
public static string cypher(string word)
{
    // If word is null, we just return null.
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
      return null;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char d in word)
    {
        char charCypher = System.Convert.ToChar((int)d+2);
        builder.Append(Convert.ToString(charCypher));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: How do you go about solving this then??

Comment: @C.Sciana as Julo has also mentioned already. your method is only able to return the first Char of a given word. Would you not need all the chars?

Comment: If the value is `null` you'll get a `NullReferenceException` https://dotnetfiddle.net/qA2T8b

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop in cypher *can* contain an empty string, so the loop won't be executed if that's the case. Therefore it won't hit your return statement.

A workaround for this problem could be adding `return String.Empty` before the last closing brace or your method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you want to implement [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher):

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static string cypher(string word) {
  //DONE: do not forget to validate public method's arguments
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
    return word;

  //TODO: you may want to make some amendments
  //  1. Filter out which characters to encode (e.g. skip new lines)
  //  2. Add modulo operator (e.g. to encode letters as letters)
  return string.Concat(word.Select(d => (char)(d + 2))); 
}
```

Please, do not forget to cast integer back to `char` when concatenating the string